# Need help to prove $(A\cup B) \setminus (C \setminus A) = A \cup (B \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

Having trouble with a discrete math question involving sets. Have been asked to prove:

$$(A\cup B) \setminus (C  \setminus A) = A \cup (B \setminus C)$$

This is what I have so far:

$x \in A$ or  $x\in (B \setminus C)$

$x \in A$ or $x\in B$ and $x\not\in  C$

This where I get stuck. I can see how to combine the $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ into $x \in A\cup B$, but I do not know how to derive the other half. Please help.

Comment: Considered just filling in a Venn diagram for each of the sides and seeing that the same areas of the diagram end up shaded?

Comment: In our course Venn diagrams cannot be used for proofs.

Comment: x @isomorphism: How about truth tables, then?

Comment: No. A formal proof is required.

Comment: x @isomorphism: What's informal about truth tables? If you want a proof in a _particular_ formal proof system, you need to disclose which rules the proof systems you use has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $x \in A \cup (B - C)$. Then ($x \in A$) OR $(x \in B$ and $x \notin C$).

If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \notin C - A$, so $x \in (A \cup B) - (C-A)$.

If $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, then $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \notin C - A$, so $x \in (A \cup B) - (C-A)$.

This means that $A \cup (B-C) \subset (A \cup B)-(C-A)$.

Comment: This solution is using the methods and notation that we learned in class. Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: What about the other direction?

Comment: D.J. proved the other direction.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a purely algebraic-looking proof, I would write
$$ \begin{align} (A\cup B)\setminus(C\setminus A)
  &= (A\cup B)\setminus(C\cap A^\complement)
\\&= (A\cup B)\cap (C\cap A^\complement)^\complement
\\&= (A\cup B)\cap (C^\complement \cup A)
\\&= A\cup(B\cap C^\complement)
\\&= A\cup(B\setminus C)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would it be possible for you to complete the algebra? I'm not too familiar with your algebraic approach but I've seen the compliment notation and I'd like to learn this method as well.

Comment: Thank you Henning, this is very helpful to add another technique to my tool kit.

Comment: On an related note. What is the markup language or tool you guys are using for your data entry in these solutions? I need to graduate to math for web.

Comment: @isomorphism: It's called MathJax and is largely the same input format as math mode in LaTeX. [Here is a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Great, thanks I will take a look. I've been dragging my heels with regard to learning LaTeX, but as an EE student I should probably learn some of it sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 3):

Proof of $\subseteq$:

Let $x \in (A \cup B) - (C - A)$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, and $x \notin (C-A)$. The last part means that either $x \in C \cap A$ or $x \notin C$.

Suppose $x \in C \cap A$. Then $x \in A$, so we're done as $A \subseteq A \cup (B-C)$.

Suppose $x \notin C$. But we also know that either $x \in A$ (in which case we're done) or $x \in B$ (in which case we're done, as $x \in (B-C)$).

I'll leave $\supseteq$ for you to try along similar lines.

Comment: Thanks D.J, this exercise is very helpful.